# Using DBContext in quartz EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im struggeling getting data from my database.
Im working with EF 6, Topshelf and Quartz.

But for now I'm using this code to get some data.

```
{
private BackgroundWorker bw;

public void Start()
{
    bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        db.Employees.Load();
    }
}
}
```

On db.Employees.Load(), im getting the accesviolation exception.

I've read that I needed to use the using statement because a EF DBContext is written as a unit of work.

Also read something about .net 4.5.2. So my project is 4.5.2. yet, but still got the issue.

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: whats the exception?

Comment: access violation at address in module read of address

Comment: post the full exception message and stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Had to run the application as x86.